# suggest ways to provide the user the choice to change the font size of page using c# and css to any digit possible

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, web

well

i have a asp.net aspx page, which references a css file

- have the font size defined in css as 2em;

### problem

- want to give option to user to change this to any value he wishes

irrespective of the bad effect to display format

### question

please suggest ways to achieve it easily, efficiently and the most simplest way possible

### note

way should support all browsers

Comment: You can't do it with C#, unless you want to dynamically modify the CSS and inject it into the page.  Are you sure the user can't just zoom the page?  That's easy enough to do by holding down the <ctrl> key and spinning the mouse wheel.

Comment: @Robert , i posted on solution , do you think that is good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very nice way of doing this is

create a config entry in the appsettings

```
<add key="CSSFontSize" value="10"/>
```

Have a div tag in your aspx page

```
<div id="cssConfigValue" style="display:none">value goes here</div> div to hold the value from config setting
```

in your c# code set the div through innerhtml

```
cssconfigValue.innerHtml="value from config"
```

Now in jquery , read this value and modify it

v`ar value = $('#cssConfigValue').text() // this gives the value`

```
$('.targeclass').css('font-size',value);
```

If you want to change all you need to change the appsettings and there is no need to change anything for deployment.

no dotnet build
no javascript change...

Comment: @user in this way you will have control before things going to production , you can verify on dev box and all you need to push to production is just the appsettings.

Comment: This doesn't allow the user to change the font size, only the developer (or someone with write access to the web.config file).  I'm not sure this it was the OP was asking for.

Comment: This seems like a very long winded way to change some CSS.  What if you wanted to set 10 settings, or 50 - you're rendering every value in a new DIV?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the CSS based on user actions.  2 approaches spring to mind:

1) Do the modification on the server (in C#).  So you need to dynamically serve the CSS and modify this line based on user settings

2) Do the modification on the client using javascript (easy enough with jquery for example).

Advantage of 1 is you can store user preferences server side.  But then it's easy enough to store preferences in cookies if you use javascript.